# Why isn't INFORMATION_SCHEMA displayed in the MySQL Workbench UI by default?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am running MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE.  The following is the default look of the UI:

[image: ![enter image description here]

I can query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database, but it is not shown by default under the SCHEMAS section in the navigator panel on the left.  Why is this, and how can I get this database to show up on the said panel?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Click on

```
Edit -> Preferences -> SQL Editor and then check the box "Show Metadata and Internal Schemas"
```

Click on Refresh icon on the right side of Schemas in the left side bar.

I am using 6.3CE. Older versions may have something similar.

Comment: @Sabuncu glad it worked out.

Comment: You really deserve an extra point for the tip on refreshing the display. Thanks again.

Comment: 2022, this answer is as usefull as it gets :) ! Thanks!