# MySQL Workbench, Windows Server 2019, MySQL not showing Performance, Information of MySQL Schemas!

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-8.0, windows-server

This evening I installed MySQL on a new clean install of Windows 2019 server. When the install finished, the installer offered the possibility of opening Workbench so I said yes.

Then I noticed that there were schemas missing - as per the question, the performance, information and mysql schemas were missing (see the screenshot below<sup>**1**</sup>)

[image]

But, when I log in using the mysql client, I get this

```
mysql> show schemas;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sakila             |
| sys                |
| world              |
+--------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

In Workbench, I can access the "missing" schemas via queries like so

```
SELECT host, user FROM mysql.user;

host,user
%,xxx
localhost,mysql.infoschema
localhost,mysql.session
localhost,mysql.sys
localhost,root
```

Can anybody explain to me what's going on here? How can I get the missing schemas to appear in MySQL Workbench?

<sup>**1**</sup> I know that screenshots are normally not a good idea in this forum, but this time, it's the only way to show what I mean.

```
>mysqld.exe --version
\mysqld.exe  Ver 8.0.18 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
```

and

```
Workbench 8.0
```

and

```
Windows Server 2019 Standard
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't INFORMATION\_SCHEMA not displayed in the MySQL Workbench UI by default?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/177796/why-isnt-information-schema-not-displayed-in-the-mysql-workbench-ui-by-default)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A similar issue, [*Information_Schema and mysql databases not shown*](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=53154), was submitted as a bug report to the MySQL Bug System nine years ago. The report was resolved as *Not a Bug* as the issue turned out to be something controlled by one of MySQL Workbench settings. Specifically, Valeriy Kravchuk suggested this resolution:

> Please, check "Show Metadata Schemata" checkbox in the Query Editor group of the SQL Editor tab in the Workbench Preferences dialog box. Use Edit > Preferences... menu item to open it. Don't forget to click "Refresh all" in the Object Browser's context menu after that.